# How do we stop a gray goo disaster?

Tags: apocalypse, nanotechnology, cataclysms

Let us imagine a scenario where the apocalypse has come in the form of gray goo: tiny nanotech replicators that are set to consume all the biomass on Earth while replicating themselves. Humans, oddly enough, don’t want this to happen, (considering that is basically what *we’re* doing). Therefore, I am trying to stop this.

Some background info: the nanites grow into “clumps” of grey material about the size of grains of sand, with the general consistency of ash. They are powered by sunlight but require very little energy, and can continue to thrive even in twilight conditions. They are composed of carbon, hydrogen, and nitrogen; they spread rapidly, covering about 4.3 meters per day over land, though they can be distributed by the wind as well.

How can I halt and maybe reverse the damage done by these critters, preferably in a timespan of 10-20 years?

Comment: Considering that you are giving zero information on how this gray goo operates, how are we supposed to come with an answer?

Comment: Pigs are grey, and they are set to consume all the biomass on Earth while replicating themselves. Fortunately, they cannot. Lots of other grey or colourful lifeforms, including humans, find pigs to be delicious, so that as prolific reproducers pigs are, and as greedy they are, nature and humans together keep them in check. The point being that trying to consume all the biomass on Earth while replicating themselves is what a zillion species do.

Comment: Each “goo” unit is composed of a cluster of nanites about the size of a grain of sand; those on the outside extract organic molecules, while those inside use them to construct new units. once the cluster reaches a certain size, it breaks apart into two new units. They are composed of carbon, hydrogen and nitrogen.

Comment: Two questions: what's it made of and what's its power source? Answer these two questions and you'll be good to go!

Comment: @user98816 Remember to edit the question with the information you add in comments. Comments are not always read.

Comment: Please make the title a question. This is a question-answer website.

Comment: Set the goo on fire?

Comment: Can it spread in water? Fresh and salt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Methods of containing/combating "grey goo" Von Neumann nanomachines?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/453/methods-of-containing-combating-grey-goo-von-neumann-nanomachines) (And if that's not enough, we have a [variety of how-to-stop-grey-goo questions on the Stack](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22grey+goo%22).)

Comment: are we trying to prevent it before or after the effect.

Comment: Is there not a huge difference in 10-20 years?

Either way, what have you tried and discarded

Answer (score 4):

**Anti-Nanite Beam**

[image]

Gray goo nanites getting you down? Need a weapon to render them harmless? Look no further than the anti-nanite beam?

**But how does it work?**

Glad you asked. As we all learnt in grade school, nanites work based on the Stern-Glochspeil principle. Each nanite creates a inverse Trojan field (commonly called just a nanite field) that resonates constructively with nearby nanites. This is what allows them to perform surgery on molecules and break and reforge atomic bonds without breaking their own atomic bonds in the process.

The anti-nanite beam works by producing an inverse-INVERSE Trojan field. This cancels the nanite field and makes the tiny robots collapse under their own weight. They return to inert organic substances.

For small nanite spills the robo dinosaur is your man. She can move and aim the beam to avoid people and cars and dogs. For large spills, we suggest prolonged exposure by a wide-angle beam. Ideally from a tower or satellite in geosynchronous orbit.

Prolonged exposure of 10-20 years can be necessary if the nanite spill is particularly deep. You see the layer of dead nanites on top insulates the living nanites on bottom. And the nanites on bottom keep turning the dead nanites into more living nanites.

Comment: Upvote for modern type gender and species nonconforming robo dinosaur who is your man but goes by she and respects people and cars and dogs and can be intimate with all 3.   But she is not going to stay in that tower all the time!  She has a lot of robo dino beaming love to share.

Comment: @Willk Welcome to the future my friend.

Answer (score 3):

**Vacuum cleaners and glass containers!**

"Oh, god! It broke free!"
[image]

"Quick! Let me grab my vacuum cleaner!"

[image]

Based on the replicators constitution, it is safe to assume that they cannot consume things that aren't organic in nature. And even if they could it would be slow and inefficient. Something like a glass container should be quite effective at keeping them in check (at least long enough until they can be disposed of). When the nanites are trapped in a glass jar the only way they could break free would be to either 1. work together like a muscle to shatter the container or 2. slowly chip away at the glass wall with their microscopic parts. Either way, there's plenty of time to react so long as they don't get into your body.

A vacuum cleaner connected to a glass container would be all you need to capture chunks of the grey goo. Afterward they can safely be chunked into a sealed vat of sulfuric acid.

How long would it take? The answer ranges between a few seconds to never. It all depends on where the goo first started spreading. Places with little to no human activity and lots of sunlight and biomass would make the ideal place for the goo to get a foothold and destroy humanity. Worse case scenario: if it gets released into the ocean we are all screwed.

Answer (score 2):

**Be Smart, Make Sure There is an Off Switch**

Any nanotech is going to be programmed and built by a mind that has an answer to, “what happens if this gets out?”  So given the fact that these tiny machines are going to be created by someone who is smart, they are going to make sure that if the grey goo breaks containment they could turn it all off.  Install an off switch, install a kill switch, program a virus that will completely delete its programming what ever it takes to stop the goo dead in its tracks.

**If the Off Switch Doesn’t Work, Fire Up An EMP**

In the same way very few people that can outsmart a bullet, very few electronics can outsmart an EMP.  So if simply turning the goo off won’t stop it once it breaks containment, frying the circuitry of everything in 10 square miles should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

**Hack the power generating structure**

/They are powered by sunlight/

Capturing radiant energy and using it for biological purposes is not a trivial matter.  Grey goo samples will be studied and their power generation method understood.  It must be based on organic molecules since these goo particles subsist on carbon nitrogen and oxygen.

Then hack it.  Fastest would be a poison - something which is to these power generating molecules as cyanide is to our own metabolic hardware.  This can be used through human agency to directly treat infected areas and entities.

Next is to produce a synthetic virus.  The virus targets the power molecules and also hijacks the goo reproduction machinery to make more virus.  When a goo particle falls apart because its power has failed, it will release virus particles and infect adjacent goo particles.  Infected airborne goo particles will spread far and wide.  Unless the goo has adaptive immunity, the virus will quickly clear the goolands.  Goo might survive in isolated refuges (perhaps in the deep earth) and so repeated outbreaks could be possible.

Answer (score 1):

## Nuke in a circle around the infected area.

[image]

As quickly as you can, you'll want to nuke the area around the grey goo. Make a ring of nukes timed to go off at the same time around your goo. You don't want any nanites to escape on the wind or in a fragment that gets tossed ahead.

## Build a nanite wall around the infected area

Build nanites with no self replication ability around the nuked area. They would be designed to hunt and kill the remaining nanites and prevent any that hid under the ground from escaping out. You can build them at an external facility so they can't be corrupted by the nanites remaining.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s assume it escapes the lab. It’s growing in various hidden places. It is a... pandemic! How do you fight a pandemic? With vaccination.

You’re going to need a second gray-ish goo, one that replicates itself in a regulated way: it ramps production in presence of the original gray goo and remains only mildly vigilant otherwise. Then you seed it everywhere.